# Grabbing only one function call from an included file

Tags: php

What's the best way to include a file, but not execute anything except for calling a single defined function, such as register("name","id")?

Comment: So this file you are wanting to include outputs data as well as containing functions you want to use on another page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor out that function in a separate file and include that file instead.

Answer (score 3):

the only way i know is this: (except of restructuring your file as *@Hasan Khan* said)

```
$mode = "call_func_func1";
include("file.php");
```

in **file.php**

```
...
if ($mode=="call_func_func1") { func1(); return; }
```

that is; check for $mode, execute func and return out.
if you have code in `...` this will be executed as well..

also note that in these cases DONT define functions in such files or they
will be **defined again**! (crash)

Answer (score 2):

When you [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) a php file, only the global code is executed, so if you put all content in (their own) functions, nothing is executed unless you call these functions explicitly